# Django-admin on react page

Tags: python, reactjs, django, iframe, django-admin

I'm trying to put the django-admin page in a react component so that it appears to the user on the frontend. it's a project just for programmers so everyone is authorized. However, I'm having difficulties using the iframe to display the page, how can I do this without harming the application's security?

I'm currently trying to use the iframe for this, but some security problems are appearing, mainly those related to crsf.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.